# React Native Tap and Pay - NFC

Tags: ios, react-native, nfc

I'm writing a React Native app and I need to incorporate the Apple Pay tap-and-go nfc functionality.

I've been researching and I've only been able to see examples or documentation regarding the 'in-app-purchase' type of payment prompts (the classic pop up that appears every time you make a purchase in an app).

I have seen

`tipsi-stripe, react-native-tap-payment, react-native-nfc-manager`

but they don't seem to do what I would expect.

What I'm looking for is a way to trigger the NFC functionality that you use in shops when you tap and pay with your phone instead of with the card in your wallet (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201239#stores).

Any suggestions on a good library that allows me to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to pay at a physical card terninal?  If so, there is nothing you do in your app to support this. This is just part of Apple Wallet and is built in to iOS.  Presenting the phone at a payment terminal will trigger it. To use Apple Pay to pay for physical goods ordered through your app but delivered outside of it, start here https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11. Yes that is what I want to achieve. I see what you mean, is there a way I can at least intercept the amount?

Comment: For the former case (physical payment at a terminal)? Absolutely not. The Apple Pay process is highly secure. Apps have no access to it.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you @Paulw11